# Determine the dimension of the subspace of all matrices that commutes with an all 1 matrix and find a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, projection-matrices

> Let $\Gamma$ denote the $n$-by-$n$ matrix which has $1$ in all its entries. Denote
> $$S := \{A \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R}) : A\Gamma = \Gamma A\}$$
> Determine the dimension of $S$, and find a basis for $S$.

Simple calculation tells that $S$ consists of all matrices with the sum of each row and column agreeing on a value. This is similar to the case of Magic matrices, so I found a literature for that and conclude that the dimension is $\,n^2 - 2n + 2\,$.

Problem is, how do I find a basis for it?

Exhausting all the possibilities by hand seems undesirable, and I can't think of a way to do it systematically.

Comment: It usually helps to look at lower dimensional examples (i.e. $n=2$). Then you should observe that the dimension can't be $n^2-2n$.

Comment: Made some mistakes. I guess it should be right now.

Comment: For $n > 2$ we have $n^2-2 n+2> n$ which makes no sense

Comment: $S$ is a subspace of $M_{n}$, which has $n^2$ as its dimension. I don't see where is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First hint:*
$\Gamma\,$ is symmetric and satisfies $\Gamma^2 =n\,\Gamma$ , so that $\,\frac1n\Gamma\,$ is an orthogonal projector. It is fairly straightforward to see that it projects onto a $1$-dimensional image. Hence $\,\frac1n\Gamma\,$ is similar to
$E_{nn}=\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 &\ldots &0 \\
\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\
 0 &\dots &1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$,
note that $E_{nn}$ has just one nonzero entry. Similarity means there is some transformation matrix $T$, and $\,TE_{nn}T^{-1}=\frac1n\Gamma\,$ holds. In this context
[you may consult this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3061227/316749) .
Consider the commutator map
$[\,\cdot\, ,E_{nn}]: \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})\to\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R}), A\mapsto AE_{nn} -E_{nn}A$,
which is linear.

*Second hint:*
$\dim\ker\, [\,\cdot\, ,E_{nn}] = (n-1)^2+1$ may be read off from
$$[A,E_{nn}] \;=\; 
\begin{pmatrix} 0 &\dots &0 &a_{1,n}\\
\vdots &\ddots &\vdots & \vdots\\
 0 &\dots &0 &a_{n-1,n}\\
 -a_{n,1} &\dots &-a_{n,n-1} &0\end{pmatrix}$$

*First question:*
How are $S$ and $\,\ker\, [\,\cdot\, ,E_{nn}]\,$ related to each other, in terms of the transformation matrix $T$ ?

*Last question:* How to systematically deduce from the preceding a basis of $S$ ?

Comment: Forgive my stupidity, but I might need more hint (and the intuition behind the first hint) :(

Comment: I expanded the first and the third section $-$ hope we get another step ahead $\,\ddot\smile$

Comment: I deduce that $A \in S$ if and only if $T^{-1}AT \in \ker [\cdot, E_{nn}]$, so to get a basis of $S$, just pick a basis of $\ker[\cdot, E_{nn}]$ (namely, the collection of matrices that has $1$ at position $(i,j)$ where either $i \neq n \neq j$ or $i = j = n$). Hope I got this right...

Comment: Yes, you have caught the hints! And the task, I'd say ...
This is a good example, that life (mathematically) gets easier & more transparent after choosing an appropriate basis.

Comment: thanks you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

If $A \in  S$ and $s$ is the sum of each line or column of $A$, then $A-\frac{s}{n} {\Gamma} \in  {\mathcal{V}}_{n}$, the space of ${n}\times{n}$ matrices which sum of each line or column is $0$. We can find a basis of ${\mathcal{V}}_{n}$ and add ${\Gamma}$ to this basis to get a basis of $S$.

Let us now suppose that $A = \left({a}_{i , j}\right) \in  {\mathcal{V}}_{n}$ and let $m = n+1$. Let $\left({x}_{1} , \cdots  , {x}_{n}\right)$ and
$\left({y}_{1} , \cdots  , {y}_{n}\right)$ be $2 n$ arbitrary scalars. Let us build a matrix $B = {b}_{i , j} \in  {\mathcal{V}}_{m}$ by defining

\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}{b}_{i , j}&=&{a}_{i , j}+{x}_{j}+{y}_{i} \quad  \text{ if } i , j  \leqslant  n\\
{b}_{i , m}&=&{-{s}_{x}}-n {y}_{i} \quad  \text{ if } i  \leqslant  n\\
{b}_{m , j}&=&{-n} {x}_{j}-{s}_{y} \quad  \text{ if } j  \leqslant  n\\
{b}_{m , m}&=&n {s}_{x}+n {s}_{y}
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

where ${s}_{x} = \sum _{j} {x}_{j}$ and ${s}_{y} = \sum _{i} {y}_{i}$. Conversely, any matrix $B \in  {\mathcal{V}}_{m}$ can be written in this way
because the ${x}_{j}$ and ${y}_{i}$ must be defined by

\begin{equation}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}  \left\{\begin{array}{lcl}{x}_{j}&=&{-\frac{1}{n}} {b}_{m , j}-\frac{1}{n} {s}_{y}\\
{y}_{i}&=&{-\frac{1}{n}} {b}_{i , m}-\frac{1}{n} {s}_{x}
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

The sums of the last line and column of $B$ plus the constraint that
${b}_{m , m} = n {s}_{x}+n {s}_{y}$ then imply that ${s}_{x} = \sum _{j} {x}_{j}$ and ${s}_{y} = \sum _{i} {y}_{i}$. It follows that the matrix
${a}_{i , j} = {b}_{i , j}-{x}_{j}-{y}_{i}$ for $i , j  \leqslant  n$
belongs to ${\mathcal{V}}_{n}$. This decomposition is not unique because we have one degree of freedom in the choice of $s_x$ an $s_y$. We could get a unique decomposition by choosing for example $s_y=0$.

From this we deduce the induction relation $\dim  {\mathcal{V}}_{n+1} = (2 n-1)+\dim  {\mathcal{V}}_{n}$,
hence $\dim {\mathcal{V}}_{n} = (n-1)^2$ because $\dim {\mathcal{V}}_{1}=0$ and the construction gives us a way to build a basis of these vector spaces by taking the matrices in factor of one of the ${x}_{j}$'s or
${y}_{i}$'s in the process.